# Is it possible to automate Token Renewal of postman if this web app uses Auth0 OAuth2.0 implicit grant?

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, auth0

Our Web App uses Auth0 for authentication. I need to access an endpoint for my QA Purposes. I was able to make Postman to access it using the 'Get New Access Token' with Type OAuth 2.0 and an access token. But the problem is, I had to do it on all of my test case. I tried to automate it using this pre-requisite script but I still get an 'Unauthorized' response body. Is my request body correct? Am I missing some parameters needed?

```
url: 'https://mywebapp-qa.auth0.com/oauth/token',
  method: 'POST',
  header: 'Content-Type:application/json',
  body:  {
          mode:'application/json',
          raw:  JSON.stringify({
                audience:'https://mywebapp.markstest.com.au',                
                scope: 'api',
                client_id: 'myclientid_',
                grant_type: 'implicit',
                redirect_uri: 'https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback',
                response_type: 'token',
                })
  }
```

Comment: Implicit flow is a redirected based flow and it is intended to be executed in the browser. But you are trying to execute as like regular REST API which will not work. To automate it, you can either execute client credentials grant type or resource owner password grant type. https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant

Comment: Thanks Tanver Hasan. I have reconsidered changing my approach. Thank you!